# How to make a cyclic class change on elements by click?

Tags: javascript, css

There are multiple buttons.

Buttons by click must change their style/class three times, without changing the style of the other buttons.

```js
var bt = document.getElementById('b1');  
var cl = ['cls cls1', 'cls cls2', 'cls cls3'];   
var current = 0;                     

bt.addEventListener ('click', function() {
  current++; 
  current %= cl.length; 
  bt.className = cl[current]; 
});
```

```css
.cls  {margin:10px 0; padding:3px 30px; 
       border:1px solid gray; outline:0; cursor:pointer;}
.cls1 {background:gold;}
.cls2 {background:aqua;}
.cls3 {background:lime;}
```

```html
<button class="cls cls1" id="b1">b1</button>
<button class="cls cls1" id="">b2</button>
<button class="cls cls1" id="">b3</button>
```

[fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Ar7en/vwyusk82/)
but works for one button 'b1' one by one id.

How to modify the example for all buttons by id?

And is there a way without id, by class on pure javascript?
Thank you.

Comment: the 'click' callback function has arguments that are passed in.  The first is event args which has a `target` property that points to the button that was currently clicked.

Comment: Good formatting on your first question here! Welcome to SO buddy :)

Answer (score 3):

By using `getElementById()` you are targeting only a single button with specific `id` passed as the parameter.

To attach `event` to all the button, you have to select all the button first. You can use `querySelectorAll()` for that. Then use `forEach()` to loop through each button and attach the `event`.

[querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

> The Element method querySelectorAll() returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

[forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> The forEach() method executes a provided function once for each array element.

**Working Code:**

```js
var bt = document.querySelectorAll('.cls.cls1');  
var cl = ['cls cls1', 'cls cls2', 'cls cls3'];                    
bt.forEach(function(b){
  var current = 0;    
  b.addEventListener ('click', function() {
    current++; 
    current %= cl.length; 
    b.className = cl[current]; 
  });
});
```

```css
.cls  {margin:10px 0; padding:3px 30px; 
       border:1px solid gray; outline:0; cursor:pointer;}
.cls1 {background:gold;}
.cls2 {background:aqua;}
.cls3 {background:lime;}
```

```html
<button class="cls cls1" id="b1">b1</button>
<button class="cls cls1" id="">b2</button>
<button class="cls cls1" id="">b3</button>
```

**Please Note:** `querySelectorAll()` has some browser issue. In that case you may try the following way by using `getElementsByClassName()`:

```js
var bt = document.getElementsByClassName('cls');  
var cl = ['cls cls1', 'cls cls2', 'cls cls3'];                    
[].forEach.call(bt, function(b){
  var current = 0;    
  b.addEventListener ('click', function() {
    current++; 
    current %= cl.length; 
    b.className = cl[current]; 
  });
});
```

```css
.cls  {margin:10px 0; padding:3px 30px; 
       border:1px solid gray; outline:0; cursor:pointer;}
.cls1 {background:gold;}
.cls2 {background:aqua;}
.cls3 {background:lime;}
```

```html
<button class="cls cls1" id="b1">b1</button>
<button class="cls cls1" id="">b2</button>
<button class="cls cls1" id="">b3</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, Mamun. But in the browser IE 11.0 does not work.

Comment: @Arsen, IE 11.0 should should support `querySelectorAll()` even though it has some browser issues. I have added another solution which does not have any browser compatibility issue...try that.....thanks

Comment: Yes, fine. Thank you, Mamun. Through `getElementsByClassName()` it works.

Comment: @Arsen, you are most welcome....if the answer solve your problem then please up-vote the answer by clicking up-arrow beside the answer and accept the answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in......thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple: you simply select all the buttons using `document.querySelectorAll('.cls')`, and then iterate through the NodeList collection and append the click event listener to each button:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.cls');
var cl = ['cls cls1', 'cls cls2', 'cls cls3'];

Array.prototype.slice.call(buttons).forEach(function(button) {
  // Each button should have its own store for the current index
  var current = 0;

  // Add event listener
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    current++;
    current %= cl.length;
    button.className = cl[current];
  });
});
```

In that way, you don't have to worry about assigning unique ID to all the buttons you want to have this behaviour applied to.

Notes:

- Use `Array.prototype.slice.call(<NodeList>)` because the `NodeList` returned by `document.querySelectorAll` is not an array *per se*. Doing this will convert it into an array where you can use `.forEach` on :)
- Remember to give each button its individual "store" for its current index. Therefore, you will have to move the `var current = 0` into the loop.

---

Proof-of-concept example:

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.cls');
var cl = ['cls cls1', 'cls cls2', 'cls cls3'];

Array.prototype.slice.call(buttons).forEach(function(button) {
  // Each button should have its own store for the current index
  var current = 0;
  
  // Add event listener
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    current++;
    current %= cl.length;
    button.className = cl[current];
  });
});
```

```css
.cls {
  color: white;
}

.cls1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.cls2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.cls3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button class="cls cls1" id="b1">b1</button>
<button class="cls cls1" id="">b2</button>
<button class="cls cls1" id="">b3</button>
```

---

If you are comfortable writing in ES6, it gets even better:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.cls');
const cl = ['cls cls1', 'cls cls2', 'cls cls3'];

Array.from(buttons).forEach((button) => {
  // Each button should have its own store for the current index
  let current = 0;
  
  // Add event listener
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    current++;
    current %= cl.length;
    button.classList = cl[current];
  });
});
```

```css
.cls {
  color: white;
}

.cls1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.cls2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.cls3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button class="cls cls1" id="b1">b1</button>
<button class="cls cls1" id="">b2</button>
<button class="cls cls1" id="">b3</button>
```

Comment: Terry, big thank for the detailed answer.
But which method is better for cross-browser compatibility?

Comment: @Arsen Definitely the first one :) only use the ES6 code when you are transpiling down to ES5, due to lack of support in older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `id`, use **tagname** in `querySelectorAll` and iterate the same using `forEach` (*most of the logic stays same*)

```
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');
var cl = ['cls cls1', 'cls cls2', 'cls cls3'];
var current = 0;

Array.from(btns).forEach(bt => bt.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  current++;
  current %= cl.length;
  e.currentTarget.className = cl[current];
}));
```

**Demo**

```js
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');
var cl = ['cls cls1', 'cls cls2', 'cls cls3'];
var current = 0;

Array.from(btns).forEach(bt => bt.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  current++;
  current %= cl.length;
  e.currentTarget.className = cl[current];
}));
```

```css
.cls1
{
   background-color: red;
}
.cls2
{
   background-color: blue;
}
.cls3
{
   background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button class="cls cls1" id="b1">b1</button>
<button class="cls cls1" id="">b2</button>
<button class="cls cls1" id="">b3</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, hurwinder372. But in the browser IE 11.0 does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Four concepts can help you here:

1) You can ask an element for its current class instead of using a counter to track the state. This way each button can track its own state instead of needing one variable per button.

2) Events can bubble up. So if you place a click handler onto the wrapper element of the buttons, all buttons will use the same event, so you can just add as many buttons you want without the need to atatch the event to each of them.

3) All events have an `event` parameter in their callback. By using `event.target`, you get a direct reference to the element that was clicked.

4) All elements have a classList object that you can use to check various things concerning their css classes.

So if we combine these, we can end up with something like this:

```js
const DEFAULT_CLASSES = [ 'cls1', 'cls2', 'cls3' ];
document.querySelector( '#comp_buttons' ).addEventListener( 'click', event => {
 if ( event.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON' ) {
  const button = event.target;
  const cls_current = DEFAULT_CLASSES.find( cls => button.classList.contains( cls ) );
  const cls_index = DEFAULT_CLASSES.indexOf( cls_current );
  const cls_next = DEFAULT_CLASSES[ cls_index + 1 ] || DEFAULT_CLASSES[ 0 ];
  button.classList.replace( cls_current, cls_next );
 }
} );
```

```css
.cls {
  color: white;
}

.cls1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.cls2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.cls3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
.cls4 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="comp_buttons">
 <button class="cls cls1">b1</button>
 <button class="cls cls1">b2</button>
 <button class="cls cls1">b3</button>
</div>
```

The big advantage of this method is that you can add any number of buttons into the div without the need to change the event handlers.

Also you can add any numbers of classes, as long as you define the class in the css and place its name into the DEFAULT_CLASSES array.
These classes can even have random names now, sicne we don't rely on a counter or a number to identify the current class of the button.